# How can I get type information at runtime from a DMP file in a Windbg extension?

Tags: c++, object, types, windbg, memory-dump

This is related to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573242/how-can-i-create-objects-based-on-dump-file-memory-in-a-windbg-extension), regarding pulling objects from a dmp file.

As I mentioned in the previous question, I can successfully pull object out of the dmp file by creating wrapper 'remote' objects.  I have implemented several of these so far, and it seems to be working well.  However I have run into a snag.

In one case, a pointer is stored in a class, say of type 'SomeBaseClass', but that object is actually of the type 'SomeDerivedClass' which derives from 'SomeBaseClass'.  For example it would be something like this:

```
MyApplication!SomeObject
   +0x000 field1            : Ptr32 SomeBaseClass
   +0x004 field2            : Ptr32 SomeOtherClass
   +0x008 field3            : Ptr32 SomeOtherClass
```

I need some way to find out what the ACTUAL type of 'field1' is.

To be more specific, using example addresses:

```
MyApplication!SomeObject
   +0x000 field1            : 0cae2e24 SomeBaseClass
   +0x004 field2            : 0x262c8d3c SomeOtherClass
   +0x008 field3            : 0x262c8d3c SomeOtherClass

0:000> dt SomeBaseClass 0cae2e24 
MyApplication!SomeBaseClass
   +0x000 __VFN_table : 0x02de89e4 
   +0x038 basefield1         : (null) 
   +0x03c basefield2        : 3

0:000> dt SomeDerivedClass 0cae2e24 
MyApplication!SomeDerivedClass
   +0x000 __VFN_table : 0x02de89e4 
   +0x038 basefield1        : (null) 
   +0x03c basefield2        : 3
   +0x040 derivedfield1     : 357
   +0x044 derivedfield2     : timecode_t
```

When I am in WinDbg, I can do this:

```
dt 0x02de89e4
```

And it will show the type:

```
0:000> dt 0x02de89e4 
SomeDerivedClass::`vftable'
Symbol  not found.
```

But how do I get that inside an extension?  Can I use SearchMemory() to look for 'SomeDerivedClass::`vftable'?   If you follow my other question, I need this type information so I know what type of wrapper remote classes to create.   I figure it might end up being some sort of case-statement, where I have to match a string to a type?  I am ok with that, but I still don't know where I can get that string that represents the type of the object in question (ie SomeObject->field1 in the above example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOH!   It was much simpler than I thought.  The virtual function tables are simply other symbols, so I can use GetSymbol() with the address of the field1's vftable.  Then simply setup a case statement with the few types I expect, and create the right one for the situation.

For example:

```
char buffer[255];
ULONG64 displacement;
GetSymbol(0x02de89e4,buffer, &displacement);

dprintf("0x%08lx = %s\n", 0x02de89e4, buffer);
```

In WinDbg when I run the extension this outputs:

```
0x02de89e4 = MyApplication!SomeDerivedClass::`vftable'
```

Simple.  Just have to parse that buffer and I should be good to go...

Comment: Nice question & answer!